# How to access any other web application's TextBox?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, iframe

How to communicate between my two web projects.
1) Firstly; You should look below pic which has got ddlCustomer(Dropdownlist) i will select a Customer. 
2) i have a iframe which has a page i Want to write this customer to add this textbox...
[image]

Comment: Read the question yourself. Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: So hard to understand your question with all that typing errors and the way questions are expressed. Do you have 2 ASP.NET pages, that you own, and you want to interact with each other?  Since you didn't attach javascript tag, that's what I got out of it.  Could you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the server side controls.
Only by javascript code to refresh the iframe.